# Issue in Translating C++ from Oreilly book to Objective-C (3D Programming for iOS)

Tags: c++, objective-c, render, glkit

I'm currently going through Oreilly's 3D Programming for iOS book and translating everything from C++ to Objective - C for numerous purposes including later optimization and in depth understanding of functions and APIs. I'd much rather learn to leverage the new GLKit rather rely on C++'s currently language specifically for iOS development. Below is the translated code I have so far for creating the 3D cone model the book provides. Unfortunately, only one sliver of both the bottom disk and the cone itself appear and I have no idea why. Would anyone be able to assist me in this. Please, if you see any optimizations (which I haven't gone over yet because I'm still translating) or suggestions for better ways of doing anything I would love to hear some feed back. I really would like assistance in finding the issue though. I've been looking for a few days without results. Attached below is an image of what I'm outputting (it should be a full 3D rounded cone).

[image]

```
   //
//  IRenderingEngine2.m
//  HelloArrow
//
//  Created by TheGamingArt on 3/4/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Brandon Levasseur. All rights reserved.
//

#import "IRenderingEngine2.h"

#define STRINGIFY(A) #A
#import "Simple.frag"
#import "Simple.vert"


static const float RevolutionsPerSecond = 1;
static const float AnimationDuration = 0.25f;
static const float coneSlices = 40.f;
static const int numberOfConeVerticies = ((coneSlices/*number of coneSlices*/ +1) *2);
static const int numberOfDiskVerticies = (coneSlices + 2);

typedef struct{
    GLKVector3 Position;
    GLKVector4 Color;
}Vertex;

typedef struct{
    GLKQuaternion Start; //starting orientation
    GLKQuaternion End; //ending orientation
    GLKQuaternion Current; //current interpolated orientation
    float Elapsed; //time span in seconds for a slerp fraction between 0 and 1
    float Duration; //time span in seconds for a slerp fraction between 0 and 1
}Animation; //enables smooth 3D transitions



@interface IRenderingEngine2(){


    GLuint framebuffer;
    GLuint colorRenderbuffer;
    GLuint depthRenderbuffer; //Because of this being 3D, need depthRender. If only 2d, only need colorRender
    float currentAngle; //angles in degrees
    float desiredAngle; //added for smooth rotation transition

    Vertex cone[numberOfConeVerticies];
    Vertex disk[numberOfDiskVerticies];
    Animation animation;


    GLuint simpleProgram;
}

-(float) getRotationDirection;
-(void)applyRotation:(float)degrees;
-(GLuint)buildProgramWithVertex:(const char *)vShaderSource andFragment:(const char *)fShaderSource;
-(void)applyOrthoWithMaxX:(float)maxX andMaxY:(float)maxY;
-(GLuint)buildShaderWithSource:(const char *)source shaderType:(GLenum)type;
-(GLKQuaternion) quaternionCreateFromVectors:(GLKVector3)v0 :(GLKVector3)v1;

@end


@implementation IRenderingEngine2
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setRenderWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height{


    const float coneRadius = 0.5f;
    const float coneHeight = 1.866f;
    //    const int coneSlices = 40;

    {
        //Generate vertices for the disk....
        //Uses triangle fan so the total number of vertices is n+2: one exxtra vertex for the center and another for closing the loop

        //Allocate space for the disk vertices.
        //m_disk.resize(coneSlices + 2)
        int vertexIterator = 0;
        disk[vertexIterator].Color = GLKVector4Make(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f, 1.0f);
        disk[vertexIterator].Position.x = 0.0f;
        disk[vertexIterator].Position.y = 1.0f - coneHeight;
        disk[vertexIterator].Position.z = 0.0f;
        vertexIterator++;

        //Initialize the rim vertices of the triangle fan
        const float dtheta = M_2_PI / coneSlices;
        for (float theta = 0.0f; vertexIterator != numberOfDiskVerticies; theta += dtheta) {
            disk[vertexIterator].Color = GLKVector4Make(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f, 1.0f);
            disk[vertexIterator].Position.x = coneRadius * cosf(theta);
            disk[vertexIterator].Position.y = 1 - coneHeight;
            disk[vertexIterator].Position.z = coneRadius * sinf(theta);
            vertexIterator++;

        }
    }

    {
        //Generate vertices for body of cone

        int vertexIterator = 0;
        //Initialize the vertices of the triangle strip.
        const float dtheta = M_2_PI /coneSlices;
        for (float theta = 0; vertexIterator != numberOfConeVerticies ; theta += dtheta) {
            //Grayscale gradient
            float brightness = abs(sinf(theta)); // creates a grayscale gradient as a cheap way to simulate lighting.. aka baked lighting hack
            GLKVector4 color = GLKVector4Make(brightness, brightness, brightness, 1);

            //Apex vertex
            cone[vertexIterator].Position = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            cone[vertexIterator].Color = color;
            vertexIterator++;

            //Rim vertex
            cone[vertexIterator].Position.x = coneRadius * cosf(theta);
            cone[vertexIterator].Position.y = 1 - coneHeight;
            cone[vertexIterator].Position.z = coneRadius * sinf(theta);
            cone[vertexIterator].Color = color;
            vertexIterator++;


        }
    }


    //Create the depth buffer
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale], height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);


    //Create the framebuffer object and attach the color buffer.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

    //Bind the color buffer for rendering
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);


    glViewport(0, 0, width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale], height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    simpleProgram = [self buildProgramWithVertex:SimpleVertexShader andFragment:SimpleFragmentShader];
    glUseProgram(simpleProgram);

    //Set the Projection Matrix
    GLint projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation(simpleProgram, "Projection");
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeFrustum(-1.6f, 1.6f, -2.4f, 2.4f, 5.0f, 10.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, &projectionMatrix.m00);

}

-(void)render{
    GLuint positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(simpleProgram, "Position");
    GLuint colorSlot = glGetAttribLocation(simpleProgram, "SourceColor");

    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorSlot);

//    animation.Current.w = 1.0f;
//    animation.End.w = 1.0f;
//    animation.Start.w = 1.0f;

    GLKMatrix4 rotation = GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(animation.Current);


    //Set the model-view matrix
    GLint modelviewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(simpleProgram, "Modelview");

    GLKMatrix4 modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelviewUniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, &modelviewMatrix.m00);

    //Draw the cone
    {
    GLsizei stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    const GLvoid *pCoords = &cone[0].Position.x;
    const GLvoid *pColors = &cone[0].Color.r; //changed here to r from x for Red

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pCoords);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pColors);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, sizeof(cone)/sizeof(Vertex));
    }

    //Draw the disk that caps off the base of the cone
    {
        GLsizei stride = sizeof(Vertex);
        const GLvoid *pCoords = &disk[0].Position.x;
        const GLvoid *pColors = &disk[0].Color.r; //changed from x to r
        glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pCoords);
        glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pColors);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, sizeof(disk)/sizeof(Vertex));

    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorSlot);



}
-(void)updateAnimationForTime:(float)timeStep{
    NSString *currentQuaternion = NSStringFromGLKQuaternion(animation.Current);
    NSString *endQuaternion = NSStringFromGLKQuaternion(animation.End);

    if ([currentQuaternion isEqualToString:endQuaternion]) {
        return;
    }

    animation.Elapsed += timeStep;

    if (animation.Elapsed >= AnimationDuration) {
        animation.Current = animation.End;
    }
    else{
        float mu = animation.Elapsed / AnimationDuration;
        animation.Current = GLKQuaternionSlerp(animation.Start, animation.End, mu);
    }

}
-(void)onRotate:(enum DeviceOrientation) orientation{

    GLKVector3 direction;

    switch (orientation) {
        case DeviceOrientationUnknown:
        case DeviceOrientationPortrait:
            direction = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            break;

        case DeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            direction = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            break;

        case DeviceOrientationFaceDown:
            direction = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            break;

        case DeviceOrientationFaceUp:
            direction = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            break;

        case DeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            direction = GLKVector3Make(+1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            break;

        case DeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            direction = GLKVector3Make(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            break;
    }

    animation.Elapsed = 0;
    animation.Start = animation.Current = animation.End;
    //   animation.End = GLKQuaternionMakeWi
    GLKVector3 vector = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.End = [self quaternionCreateFromVectors:vector :direction];
    // (GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), direction);


}

-(float)getRotationDirection{
    float delta = desiredAngle - currentAngle;
    // NSLog(@"delta: %f", delta);

    if (delta == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    bool counterclockwise = ((delta > 0 && delta <= 180) || (delta < -180));

    float test = counterclockwise ? +1.0 : -1.0;
    NSLog(@"Return Value: %f",test );
    return counterclockwise ? +1 : -1; //problem

}


-(void)applyRotation:(float)degrees{

}


-(void)applyOrthoWithMaxX
:(float)maxX andMaxY:(float)maxY{

}

-(GLuint)buildProgramWithVertex:(const char *)vShaderSource andFragment:(const char *)fShaderSource{
    GLuint vertexShader = [self buildShaderWithSource:vShaderSource shaderType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
    GLuint fragmentShader = [self buildShaderWithSource:fShaderSource shaderType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

    GLuint programHandle = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(programHandle);

    GLint linkSuccess;
    glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);
    if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"%s", messages);
        exit(1);
    }

    return programHandle;

}

-(GLuint)buildShaderWithSource:(const char *)source shaderType:(GLenum)type{
    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &source, 0);
    glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

    GLint compileSuccess;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileSuccess);

    if (compileSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"%s", messages);
        exit(1);
    }
    return shaderHandle;
}

-(GLKQuaternion) createFromAxis:(GLKVector3)axis withAngle:(float)radians //Minor calculating issues
{
    GLKQuaternion q;
    q.w = cosf(radians / 2);
    q.x = q.y = q.z = sinf(radians / 2);
    q.x *= axis.x;
    q.y *= axis.y;
    q.z *= axis.z;
    return q;
}


-(GLKQuaternion) quaternionCreateFromVectors:(GLKVector3)v0 :(GLKVector3)v1 // Minor calculating issues
{

    GLKVector3 v1Negative = GLKVector3Negate(v1);

    NSLog(@"strings: v0: %@ v1:%@", NSStringFromGLKVector3(v0), NSStringFromGLKVector3(v1Negative));
    if (/*NSStringFromGLKVector3(v0) == NSStringFromGLKVector3(v1Negative)*/ v0.g == v1Negative.g)
        return [self createFromAxis:GLKVector3Make(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) withAngle:M_1_PI];

    GLKVector3 c =  GLKVector3CrossProduct(v0, v1);//  v0.Cross(v1);
    int d = GLKVector3DotProduct(v0, v1); // v0.Dot(v1);
    int s = sqrt((1 + d) *2);


    GLKQuaternion q;
    q.x = c.x / s;
    q.y = c.y / s;
    q.z = c.z / s;
    q.w = s / 2.0f;
    return q;
}


@end
```

For the most part, I want to get this running and then need to learn how to implement GLKQuanternions to add in methods such as

```
m_animation.End = Quaternion::CreateFromVectors(vec3(0, 1, 0), direction);
```

AKA:

```
inline QuaternionT<T> QuaternionT<T>::CreateFromVectors(const Vector3<T>& v0, const Vector3<T>& v1)
{
    if (v0 == -v1)
        return QuaternionT<T>::CreateFromAxisAngle(vec3(1, 0, 0), Pi);

    Vector3<T> c = v0.Cross(v1);
    T d = v0.Dot(v1);
    T s = std::sqrt((1 + d) * 2);

    QuaternionT<T> q;
    q.x = c.x / s;
    q.y = c.y / s;
    q.z = c.z / s;
    q.w = s / 2.0f;
    return q;
}
```

As a temporary add in, I've created the same methods for Quaternions in Objective-C

```
-(GLKQuaternion) createFromAxis:(GLKVector3)axis withAngle:(float)radians //Minor calculating issues
{
    GLKQuaternion q;
    q.w = cosf(radians / 2);
    q.x = q.y = q.z = sinf(radians / 2);
    q.x *= axis.x;
    q.y *= axis.y;
    q.z *= axis.z;
    return q;
}


-(GLKQuaternion) quaternionCreateFromVectors:(GLKVector3)v0 :(GLKVector3)v1 // Minor calculating issues
{

    GLKVector3 v1Negative = GLKVector3Negate(v1);

    NSLog(@"strings: v0: %@ v1:%@", NSStringFromGLKVector3(v0), NSStringFromGLKVector3(v1Negative));
    if (/*NSStringFromGLKVector3(v0) == NSStringFromGLKVector3(v1Negative)*/ v0.g == v1Negative.g)
        return [self createFromAxis:GLKVector3Make(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) withAngle:M_1_PI];

    GLKVector3 c =  GLKVector3CrossProduct(v0, v1);//  v0.Cross(v1);
    int d = GLKVector3DotProduct(v0, v1); // v0.Dot(v1);
    int s = sqrt((1 + d) *2);


    GLKQuaternion q;
    q.x = c.x / s;
    q.y = c.y / s;
    q.z = c.z / s;
    q.w = s / 2.0f;
    return q;
}
```

Comment: You know, you can use C++ in Objective C, right?

Comment: Not only that, but C/C++ is usually faster than Objective-C. One of the main benefits of GLKit is the ability to bypass multiple buffers  which can be daunting for a beginner (so if you're already familiar/comfortable with them, then I'm not sure using GLKit is to your advantage). I'm a big fan of the O'Reilly book, but mostly use it as reference material.

Comment: I absolutely know I can use C++ (as I'm clearly going through a book that uses C++ and Objective-C together...), I have reasons for not wanting to use it. C++ ranks just about the same as Objective-C in terms of speed but also varies depending on what you're leveraging and integrating with. This is a debatable discussion in it's own (vectors actually work a little slower than NSDictionaries and so forth). I'm purposefully trying to push an leverage native APIs though while concurrently learning the C++ ways. I want to learn how this would translate to the other end.

Comment: For the most part, whatever is referenced above shouldn't be a huge difference from it's C++ counterpart. I'm personally just trying to figure out why it's only rendering some of the cone/disk rather all. The leverage you're referencing with not bypassing multiple buffers can obviously still be utilized as well as shown above. It's pretty much all just C in essence.

Comment: Good response. It seems like I underestimated your knowledge of C languages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I didn't realize the the Pi function in the cmath was const float Pi = 4 * std::stan(1.0f). All I had to do was recalculate to const float dtheta = (M_PI * 2) / coneSlices; and voila. I would like any suggestions on improvements though.

Comment: I can suggest an improvement on your French - the word is "voila", not "vwala" :)

Comment: Woooow, the sad part is, I'm legit-ly French in a sense. Either or, +1 for smart assness lol.

Answer (score 0):

On top of before, I also simplified my Quaternion code into the following:

```
-(GLKQuaternion) createQuaternionFromAnchor:(GLKVector3)anchor direction:(GLKVector3)direction
{

    GLKVector3 axis = GLKVector3CrossProduct(anchor, direction);

    if (GLKVector3Negate(direction).g == anchor.g) {
        axis = GLKVector3Make(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }


    float dot = GLKVector3DotProduct(anchor, direction);
        float angle = acosf(dot);
        GLKQuaternion Q_rot = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndVector3Axis(angle, axis);
        Q_rot = GLKQuaternionNormalize(Q_rot);
        return Q_rot;
}
```

I did a bit of research into the GLKit source code and finally was able to see how everything worked on the back end. Math wise, they really should document how the data is handled between vectors and matrices considering everything was not as it seemed.